# Is good to write DOM code in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Today i am creating a page with angular, in controller i am write some jquery Code for toggle div.

Now my question is , is it good practice to write DOM level code in controller or create a directive for this, but i am want such type of code again and again.

```
 vm.getDetails = function (id, event) {
                $('.more-row').slideUp(300);
                $('.open-content').text("+");
                if ($(event.currentTarget).hasClass('open-content')) {
                    $('.open-content').removeClass('open-content');
                    return;
                }
                service.getDetails(id, function (err, model, logs) {
                    if(err) return;
                    vm.model.items = model;
                    vm.model.logs = logs;
                    vm.model.payRunDetailId = id;

                    $(event.currentTarget).parent().parent().next().find('td').stop().slideToggle();
                    $(event.currentTarget).addClass('open-content');
                    $(event.currentTarget).text("-");
                });
};
```

Comment: In most of the cases, you don't need to (and shouldn't) do direct DOM manipulations when using AngularJS. And if you really have to, the controller is definitely not the place to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its definitely **really bad** practice. The HTML should go to View or as you pointed out to directive. Controller should just manage the control flow of aplication.

Is this what you are looking for?

https://github.com/EricWVGG/AngularSlideables

there is also link to jsfiddle